# Как оптимизировать деплой через docker-compose?

Tags: php, docker, gitlab, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

Мы реализовали деплой через `GitLab CI` и `docker-compose`. В процессе деплоя на удалённый сервер копируется файл `docker-compose.yml` и файлы `Dockerfile` и пр. для создания "вспомогательных" контейнеров типа `nginx` и `mysql`

Всё работает как нужно. Беспокоят 2 момента: даунтайм и "мусорные" образы docker (те, что с `<none>` в колонке TAG в `docker images`)

Вот кусок файла `.gitlab-ci.yml`, ответственный собственно на деплой на удалённый сервер:

```
.template-secure-copy: &secure-copy
    stage: deploy
    image: covex/alpine-git:1.0
    before_script:
      - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
      - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    script:
      - ssh -p 22 $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST 'set -e ;
          rm -rf '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"'_tmp ;
          mkdir -p '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"'_tmp'
      - scp -P 22 -r build/* ''"$DEPLOY_USER"'@'"$DEPLOY_HOST"':'"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"'_tmp' # */ <-- в оригинале строка не закоментирована =)
      - ssh -p 22 $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST 'set -e ;
          cd '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"'_tmp ;
          docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p '"$CI_JOB_TOKEN"' '"$CI_REGISTRY"' ;
          docker-compose pull ;
          if [ -d '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"' ]; then cd '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"' && docker-compose down --rmi local && rm -rf '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"'; fi ;
          cp -r '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"'_tmp '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"' ;
          cd '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"' ;
          docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans ;
          docker-compose exec -T php phing app-deploy -Dsymfony.env=prod ;
          rm -rf '"$DEPLOY_DIRECTORY"'_tmp'
    tags:
      - executor-docker
```

Даунтайм сейчас - это 1-2-3 минуты. Начинается он с `docker-compose down ...` и до конца выполнения скрипта. Хочется его уменьшить.

А как сделать так, чтобы "мусорные" образы docker не появлялись - я вообще не понял. Про `docker image prune` знаю, хочется не очищать, а не захламлять.

UPD1:

Файл `docker-compose.yml` создаётся следующей конструкцией:

```
.template-docker-compose: &docker-compose
    stage: build
    image: covex/docker-compose:1.0
    script:
      - for name in `env | awk -F= '{if($1 ~ /'"$ENV_SUFFIX"'$/) print $1}'`; do
          eval 'export '`echo $name|awk -F''"$ENV_SUFFIX"'$' '{print $1}'`'='$"$name"'';
        done
      - mkdir build
      - docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml config > build/docker-compose.yml
      - sed -i 's/\/builds\/'"$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE"'\/'"$CI_PROJECT_NAME"'/\./g' build/docker-compose.yml
      - cp -R docker build
    artifacts:
        untracked: true
        name: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
        paths:
          - build/
    tags:
      - executor-docker
```

В результате этой процедуры получается такой `docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
  nw_external:
    external:
      name: graynetwork
  nw_internal: {}
services:
  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: project
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: project
    expose:
    - '3306'
    networks:
      nw_internal: null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - database:/var/lib/mysql:rw
  nginx:
    build:
      args:
        app_php: app
        server_name: project-dev1.ru
      context: ./docker/nginx
    depends_on:
      php:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      nw_external:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.13
      nw_internal: null
    ports:
    - 80/tcp
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
    - service:php:ro
  php:
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      ENV_database_host: mysql
      ENV_database_name: project
      ENV_database_password: project
      ENV_database_port: '3306'
      ENV_database_user: project
      ENV_mailer_from: andrey@mindubaev.ru
      ENV_mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
      ENV_mailer_password: 'null'
      ENV_mailer_transport: smtp
      ENV_mailer_user: 'null'
      ENV_secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    expose:
    - '9000'
    image: gitlab.site.ru:5005/dev1-projects/symfony:master
    networks:
      nw_internal: null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /composer/vendor
    - /srv
version: '2.1'
volumes:
  database: {}
```

Dockerfile для сервиса nginx

```
FROM nginx:alpine
ARG server_name=docker.local
ARG app_php=app_dev

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN sed -i 's/@SERVER_NAME@/'"$server_name"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
    && sed -i 's/@APP@/'"$app_php"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Dockerfile для сервиса mysql

```
FROM mysql:5.7

HEALTHCHECK CMD mysqladmin ping --silent
```

Comment: вы это используете для развертывания в production?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ну собственно до production пока не дошло, т.к. ещё по настоящему не внедряли. Как доделаем - будет в первый раз

Comment: @MikhailVaysman но там так получилось, что разницы между рабочим или тестовым сайтом - нет. Деплой происходит одинаково

Comment: добавьте **docker-compose.yml** в вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил. но он создаётся автоматически и не очень человекочитаем (там всё отсортировано не по смыслу, а по алфавиту)

Comment: Вопрос мне нравится, ответа не знаю. Если через день не будет хорошего ответа, напишите мне — назначу награду за вопрос.

Comment: Как обещал, открыл конкурс.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно минимум два контейнера, которые будет zero downtime. Дальше процесс ([хорошо описан тут](https://github.com/vincetse/docker-compose-zero-downtime-deployment)): остановить один старый, запустиить один новый и так по очереди.

Но я буквально пару недель назад все это проходил и docker swarm это ОЧЕНЬ ПРОСТО, там пару команд, рецепт по ссылке в несколько раз сложнее. Для своего решения нужно настраивать балансировщик, а в docker swarm уже все есть и ставиться, ещё раз скажу, ОЧЕНЬ ПРОСТО.

Переходите сразу на docker swarm. Он очень быстро настраивается и нулевой downtime из коробки.

Просто docker service отличный инструмент, а docker stack вообще бомба (как раз поднимает все оружение из docker-compose подобного файла).

Comment: к сожалению, мы не сможем перейти на docker swarm и docker stack использовать тоже не сможем - это слишком сложно организационно. сначала перейдём просто на docker

Comment: Нужно минимум два контейнера, которые будет zero downtime. Дальше процесс хорошо описано тут https://github.com/vincetse/docker-compose-zero-downtime-deployment ... остановить один старый, запустиить один новый и так по очереди. Но я буквально пару недель назад все это проходил и docker swarm это ОЧЕНЬ ПРОСТО, там пару команд, рецепт по ссылке в несколько раз сложнее. Для своего решения нужно настраивать балансировщик, а в docker swarm уже все есть и ставиться, ещё раз скажу, ОЧЕНЬ ПРОСТО.

Comment: @alexes а вот это уже похоже на хороший ответ. Может быть, напишете краткую инструкцию прямо здесь? Ссылки — штука ненадежная, тем более там инструкция на английском, ее можно перевести.

Comment: Есть же официальный гайд: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ На swarm не нужно "переходить", это теперь из коробки в `docker-[ce]e`

Comment: @vp_arth так напишите, как его использовать. С меня 50 репы. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin идея по ссылке @alexes очень сильно помогла! даунтайм теперь около **8 секунд**! Теперь непонятно как его отследить и измерить =) После конкурса выложу своё решение. А совсем потом буду смотреть в сторону `docker swarm`

Comment: @АндрейМиндубаев а почему после конкурса-то? Можно и сейчас. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin выложил своё решение. Мне нужно было время чтобы всё протестировать и допилить. Плюс я до сих пор надеюсь, что будет ответ про `docker swarm` =) Хотя, и там, наверное будет downtime для обновление структуры БД

Answer (score 4):

Я существенно уменьшил downtime при деплое изменений на удалённый сервер, используя совет @alexes! Теперь downtime длится где-то **около 5 секунд**. Точнее, 5 секунд длится перезагрузка контейнера `nginx` и проверка обновлений для контейнеров `nginx` и `mysql`. А т.к. эта операция по большому счёту не обязательная, то *downtime можно избежать вообще*.

В данный момент на удалённый сервер копируется только файл `docker-compose.yml`, все сервисы в этом файле используют уже готовый образ `image`, вместо `build`. Эти образы подготавливаются до внедрения приложения на сервер.

Вместо одного сервиса с php-кодом, сейчас используется два абсолютно одинаковых: `php` и `spare`.

Также операции по подготовке кэша приложения `Symfony` (`cache:warmup`) и статичных файлов подключаемых модулей `bundles` (`assets:install`) сейчас производятся в процессе подготовки образа приложения.

В итоге, процедура деплоя получилась следующей:

1. Загружаем новые образы всего приложения
2. Обновляем и перезапускаем контейнер `spare`
3. Обновляем статичные файлы
4. Вносим изменения в структуру БД
5. Обновляем и перезапускаем контейнер `php`
6. Перезапускаем контейнер `nginx`

```bsh
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d --no-recreate
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps spare
docker-compose exec -T spare sh -c "cd /srv && rm -rf b/* && cp -a web/. b/ && rm -rf a/* && cp -a web/. a/"
docker-compose exec -T spare phing storage-prepare database-deploy
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps php
docker-compose stop nginx
docker-compose up -d nginx
```

Эту процедуру можно запускать как для инициализации, так и для обновления приложения.

Конфигурация `nginx`. Здесь оба контейнера включены в `upstream`. Когда один из них становится недоступным во время обновления, он временно исключается из `upstream` самим nginx. Конструкция `try_files /a$uri /b$uri /web$uri /app.php$is_args$args;` позволяет отдавать правильные статичные файлы во время деплоя.

```bsh
upstream backend {
    server php:9000 fail_timeout=5s;
    server spare:9000 fail_timeout=5s;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /srv/web;
    server_name site.ru;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        root /srv;
        try_files /a$uri /b$uri /web$uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass backend;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/web$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /srv/web;
        internal;
    }

    location /upload/ {
        root /srv/storage;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    sendfile off;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

Новый файл `docker-compose.yml`

```
networks:
  nw_external:
    external:
      name: graynetwork
  nw_internal: {}
services:
  mysql:
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: project
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: project
    expose:
    - '3306'
    image: covex/mysql:5.7
    networks:
      nw_internal: null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - database:/var/lib/mysql:rw
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: gitlab.site.ru:5005/dev1-projects/symfony-workflow2/nginx:master
    networks:
      nw_external:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.13
      nw_internal: null
    ports:
    - 80/tcp
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - assets:/srv/a:ro
    - assets:/srv/b:ro
    - assets:/srv/storage:ro
  php:
    environment:
      ENV_database_host: mysql
      ENV_database_mysql_version: '5.7'
      ENV_database_name: project
      ENV_database_password: project
      ENV_database_port: '3306'
      ENV_database_user: project
      ENV_mailer_from: andrey@mindubaev.ru
      ENV_mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
      ENV_mailer_password: 'null'
      ENV_mailer_transport: smtp
      ENV_mailer_user: 'null'
      ENV_secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    image: gitlab.site.ru:5005/dev1-projects/symfony-workflow2:master
    networks:
      nw_internal: null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - assets:/srv/a:rw
    - assets:/srv/b:rw
    - assets:/srv/storage:rw
  spare:
    environment:
      ENV_database_host: mysql
      ENV_database_mysql_version: '5.7'
      ENV_database_name: project
      ENV_database_password: project
      ENV_database_port: '3306'
      ENV_database_user: project
      ENV_mailer_from: andrey@mindubaev.ru
      ENV_mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
      ENV_mailer_password: 'null'
      ENV_mailer_transport: smtp
      ENV_mailer_user: 'null'
      ENV_secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    image: gitlab.site.ru:5005/dev1-projects/symfony-workflow2:master
    networks:
      nw_internal: null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - assets:/srv/a:rw
    - assets:/srv/b:rw
    - assets:/srv/storage:rw
version: '2.1'
volumes:
  assets: {}
  database: {}
```

Comment: Не меняйте на ходу конфиг nginx. Сделайте upstream с несколькими серверами на разные порты и поставьте маленький timeout. У вас всегда должен быть хотя бы один интанс php контейнера, способного дать ответ nginx, пока другие обновляются. Назовите контейнеры типа php1, php2, php3 и обновляйте их по очереди... остановили первый, обновляете, в это время nginx увидел, что что-то не то с ним и временно выкинул его из upstream.

Comment: Если вы можете без напрягов запускать 2 контейнера, всегда это делайте + сверху балансировщик. Контейнеры иногда падают и перезапускаются минуту или вроде того... вам это не нужно.

Comment: @alexes я пробовал сделать две записи server в upstream, а "запасной" сервер пометить как `backup`. но там в какой-то момент `nginx` начал отказываться работать и постоянно перегружался из-за того, что не существовало контейнера `php` (не смогу дать подробности - была поздняя ночь =) Плюс есть такая проблема, что обновлённый контейнер может работать только с обновлённой структурой БД, а старый - только со старой. Получается, что я не могу ни оставить старый контейнер с новой структурой БД, ни запусть обновлённый контейнер со старой структурой БД. Плюс надо ещё `nginx` и `mysql` надо обновлять

Comment: Зачем обновлять nginx и mysql? Там ну раз в год версии обновить и все. Не нужно помечать второй php как backup. Сделайте два постоянно работабщих php на разных портах, обновляйте по очереди.

Comment: Крайне редко старый контейнер падает из-за миграций. Ну раз упадёт то в крайне редкий ситуациях, не страшно...

Comment: @alexes ладно! я всё понял =) получается, что я и с обновлениями `nginx` и `mysql`, и с попытками исключить возможность неправильной работы `php` с новой структурой, - обрабатывал исключильные случаи, из-за которых эти 10 секунд downtime появляются **вообще** каждый раз. Приглушу своё чуство прекрасного и переделаю. В любом случае, "неправильная работа" контейнера `php` в течении секунды **уже** в тысячи раз лучше, чем это есть у нас в данный момент!

Comment: @alexes я изменил свой ответ. Получилось здорово и даже работает =) Обновление nginx и mysql оставил с оговоркой, и если это не учитывать - практически zero-downtime deployment получился! =) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Я использую команду без downtime:

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service>
```

Пример:

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build nginx
```